# What previous javac errors prevent a checkerFramework checker from running in a class?

Tags: build.gradle, checker-framework

I am using the [checkerFramework](https://checkerframework.org/manual/) gradle plugin to statically analyze nullness and tainting in my code.  When I run the checker via gradle, only one of my classes are properly checked.  All the other classes return with the ambiguous error about the checker not running:

```
error: [type.checking.not.run] NullnessChecker did not run because of a previous error issued by ja
vac
public class Main {
       ^
```

The manual linked does not metion what potentially causes this.  I had some [@Nullable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/nullable-and-notnull-annotations.html) annotations prepended to some static instance variables of the primary class I am using, but undoing those did not fix the issue.

My build.gradle is set up like so:

```
plugins {
    // Checker Framework pluggable type-checking
    id 'org.checkerframework' version '0.6.3'
}

checkerFramework {
checkers = [
        'org.checkerframework.checker.nullness.NullnessChecker',
        'org.checkerframework.checker.tainting.TaintingChecker'
           ]
}


apply plugin: 'org.checkerframework'
```

Where do I find more detail on this error?

Answer (score 0):

You didn't show the full javac output.  The relevant errors should be just above the `error: [type.checking.not.run]` line that you did show.

The Checker Framework runs as a plugin to javac.  When javac issues an error in one class (including any Checker Framework error), javac may or may not process other classes.  Unfortunately, there is no good way for a user to predict how far javac will get.  Your best bet is to [focus on the code that matters most to you](https://checkerframework.org/manual/#get-started-start-small), and resolve each error in turn before proceeding to other classes.

**Update:** The Checker Framework no longer issues `type.checking.not.run` errors.

Comment: Should `type.checking.not.run` then be a `warning` rather than a `error`? Currently, it is hard to find the true error as the log contains lots of errors (100 of them), and only the first is really important while the others are just for information purpose.